# How can we resend a data fetched from database using PHP

Tags: php

Actually, I am fetching questions from the MYSQL database with their options and true answer is stored in database with question Id, now I want to resend that  option which will user select, please tell me how can it possible by PHP?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly as it will vastly improve your chances of getting good answers in return and not have your question downvoted or closed.